# SQLiteCommand.CommandTimeout behavior

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've got a C# program that uses SQLite as the data store and as the ASP.NET membership & profile repositories.  The program is not an ASP.NET application; it is a WPF application that uses the ASP.NET membership & profile providers.  This program is the front-end for our application.

Just before the program terminates, it writes data to the user's profile.  The connection string in app.config sets the default timeout to 120 seconds.  However, I've seen cases where the operation may take a lot longer than 120 seconds, like it's still waiting to shut down after 2 hours.

According to the documentation for the SQLiteCommand.CommandTimeout property, the property is:

> The amount of time to wait for the connection to become available before erroring out

I got this bit of information from the SQLite.NET.chm file that I downloaded with the package.

This description does not sound like the property controls how long the program waits for the query to complete; it sounds like it's waiting for the connection to become available, and if it is available quickly, but the query doesn't complete right away, you could wait a long time.  Like in the case of a deadlock (there is another application that uses the same database; it's this program's back end).

Am I right? Or will the operation timeout if the query doesn't complete in the time specified in this property?

Answer (score 2):

We have a copy of the source code for the System.Data.SQLite.dll library that we downloaded some time ago so I opened it & looked for places where the `CommandTimeout` property is used.  It turns out the only references I could find were in two internal methods called `Step` and 'Reset`.  The`Step` method is called passing a prepared statement and returns one row of data.  It's called repeatedly until all of the data that the statement returns has been received.

This method does not perform any kind of wait.  It calls the native `sqlite3_step` method and, if that returns an error code, only checks to see if it has waited longer than the period specified by the `CommandTimeout` property.  If it has, it throws an exception.  If it hasn't, it tries again if it can.

So the answer to my question is that the `CommandTimeout` property does not control how long your program will wait for a SQL statement to complete, which is how it works with other databases I've used.